# Laravel Error leftJoin : Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i'm using the leftJoin on laravel, but it get an error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

here the sample code on Controller

```
$news = News::find($id)
            ->leftJoin('categories', 'news.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->get();

    //dd($news);

    return view('news.update')
    ->with('news', $news);
```

I've been trying using get()->first() but it just show the first record only. 
And if i using foreach on blade like this, the error is just the same

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/news/{{$news->id}}" method="post" enctype="mulipart/form-data">
<select name="category_id">
    <option> - </option>
    @foreach($news as $news)
    <option value="{{ $news->category_id }}" selected>{{ $news->category }}</option>
    @endforeach 
</select> </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this

```
$news = DB::table('news')
          ->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'news.category_id')
          ->select('news.*', 'categories.*')
          ->get();
```

->select('news.*', 'categories.*') // To select all records from news and category

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/news/{{$news[0]->id}}" method="post" enctype="mulipart/form-data">
  <select name="category_id">
      <option> - </option>
      @foreach($news as $news_data)
        <option value="{{ $news_data->category_id }}" selected>{{ $news_data->category }}</option>
      @endforeach 
  </select> 
</form>
```

Comment: hi, its working :)
thank you for your help, but can you explain what $news[0] mean ? is it call the index of array like this ?

Collection {#178 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#168 ▶}
    1 => {#180 ▶}
    2 => {#186 ▶}
    3 => {#187 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: $news[0] to get first record from news array